# Dealing with large numbers in R [Inf] and Python

Tags: python, r

I am learning Python these days, and this is probably my first post on Python. I am relatively new to R as well, and have been using R for about a year. I am comparing both the languages while learning Python. I apologize if this question is too basic.

I am unsure why R outputs `Inf` for something python doesn't. Let's take `2^1500` as an example.

**In R:**

```
nchar(2^1500)
[1] 3
2^1500
[1] Inf
```

**In Python:**

```
len(str(2**1500))
Out[7]: 452
2**1500
Out[8]: 3507466211043403874...
```

I have two questions:

**a) Why is it that R provides `Inf` when Python doesn't.**

**b)** I researched [How to work with large numbers in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22466328/how-to-work-with-large-numbers-in-r) thread. It seems that `Brobdingnag` could help us out with dealing with large numbers. However, even in such case, I am unable to compute `nchar`. **How do I compute above expression i.e. 2^1500 in R**

```
2^Brobdingnag::as.brob(500)
[1] +exp(346.57)
> nchar(2^Brobdingnag::as.brob(500))
Error in nchar(2^Brobdingnag::as.brob(500)) : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

Comment: look at `.Machine$double.xmax` (and other limits contained in `Machine`)

Comment: if you really just want to know the number of digits, it's `1500*log10(2)`-ish

Comment: @Michael - Thanks for your help. I ran `.Machine$double.xmax` and got `1.797693e+308`. Also, `2^1500` is just an example. I am more concerned about getting the same answer in R, like Python, rather than `Inf`. I'd appreciate your help. Also, I am unsure whether machine limitations will exist because Python is able to provide me with an answer, while R isn't giving me the answer. I am very surprised.

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538551/handling-very-large-numbers-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Large powers in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318985/large-powers-in-r)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In answer to your questions:

a)  They use different representations for numbers.  Most numbers in R are represented as double precision floating point values.  These are all 64 bits long, and give about 15 digit precision throughout the range, which goes from -double.xmax to double.xmax, then switches to signed infinite values.  R also uses 32 bit integer values sometimes.  These cover the range of roughly +/- 2 billion.  R chooses these types because it is geared towards statistical and numerical methods, and those rarely need more precision than double precision gives.  (They often need a bigger range, but usually taking logs solves that problem.)

Python is more of a general purpose platform, and it has types discussed in MichaelChirico's comment.

b) Besides `Brobdingnag`, the `gmp` package can handle arbitrarily large integers.  For example,

```
> as.bigz(2)^1500
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 35074662110434038747627587960280857993524015880330828824075798024790963850563322203657080886584969261653150406795437517399294548941469959754171038918004700847889956485329097264486802711583462946536682184340138629451355458264946342525383619389314960644665052551751442335509249173361130355796109709885580674313954210217657847432626760733004753275317192133674703563372783297041993227052663333668509952000175053355529058880434182538386715523683713208549376
> nchar(as.character(as.bigz(2)^1500))
[1] 452
```

I imagine the `as.character()` call would also be needed with `Brobdingnag`.

Comment: good so far.  Might be worth (1) incorporating details from @MichaelChirico's comment in your answer (comments are ephemeral); (2) commenting that Python only handles arbitrarily large *integers*, e.g. `2.01**1500` gives an `OverflowError` in Python (whereas `2.01^1500` gives `Inf` in R ...) unless you use something like [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/) ...

Comment: The Brobdingnag package doesn't define `as.character()`.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently python uses arbitrary precision integers by default when needed. R does not. However, there are many useful R packages to perform arbitrary precision arithmetic. Which package to pick depends on the use case.

To bring up a package that hasn't been discussed yet, consider the `Rmpfr` package:

```
> library(Rmpfr)
> a <- 2^mpfr(1500, 10000)
> a
1 'mpfr' number of precision  10000   bits 
[1] 35074662110434038747627587960280857993524015880330828824075798024790963850563322203657080886584969261653150406795437517399294548941469959754171038918004700847889956485329097264486802711583462946536682184340138629451355458264946342525383619389314960644665052551751442335509249173361130355796109709885580674313954210217657847432626760733004753275317192133674703563372783297041993227052663333668509952000175053355529058880434182538386715523683713208549376
```

It requires you to set a precision, but if you make it large enough it can hold 2^1500 as integer.

However, it also doesn't seem to define an `as.character()` function:

```
> as.character(a)
[1] "<S4 object of class \"mpfr1\">"
```

So if your problem is specifically to count digits, then the `gmp` package as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47964408/4975218) is probably the way to go. On the other hand, if you're interested in arbitrary precision *floating point* arithmetic, `Rmpfr` might be a better choice.