# Write large numbers into a file in R

Tags: r, largenumber

I want to write a vector into a file and then read it using Rstudio. The vector includes some large integers (numbers are of order 10^40) and it seems that It can not be written properly since when I want to read it I keep getting these errors:

"ReadList::readn: Invalid real number found when reading from "/Users/Research/RF_improvment/testNTT.txt."

and

"Part::partw: Part 1025 of {$Failed} does not exist.
Set::partw: Part 1025 of {Mod[$Failed + {$Failed}[[1025]], 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129461761]} does not exist."

Does anyone know how to write large numbers into a file using write function in R? I do not have a problem with calculations and the errors are for reading and writing into a file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Large powers in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318985/large-powers-in-r)

Comment: Honestly the simplest way is to just treat it as a character string, though there's probably a more robust approach.

Comment: can you say **exactly** how you're reading/writing this file? Are you using base R functions (`read.table`/`read.csv`/etc.), or tidyverse analogs, or clicking on RStudio "import/export" buttons?

Comment: @Ben Bolker I use "write" function to write the data and then "read.csv" to read it.

Comment: How are you storing such big numbers in the first place? I don't believe any of the default packages support such large integers.

Comment: @andrew.punnett I do not have any problem with calculation of these large integers and I do not store them in advance.

Comment: It would really help to know what class of object you are trying to save, but short of that I would think the `save` and `load` functions would be the best bet.

Comment: @andrew.punnett  I have a numeric vector that I write into a file using "write" function. Then I use Mathematica to read this file and do some process on it and then I read the result of Mathematica using read.csv. I am not sure if I can use save and load, because I need some formats that work with Mathematica.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as unclear, for now. As far as any of us can tell you must be using some packages beyond base R, and the answers will depend on the details of what you're doing. Can you construct a [mcve] ... ?

Answer (score 1):

The Maximum integer R can work with can be found this way:

```
> .Machine$integer.max
# [1] 2147483647
>
```

So no write or read function within R can deal with integers of this magnitude:

```
# So when you compute large numbers using R
# they are computed with double precision: 
options("scipen"=400, "digits"=4)

anum <- 10^40
bnum <- 9^40

# The above numbers are no longer integers, 
# but rather floating values calculated with double precision:
str(anum)
num 10000000000000000304008240626848262428282
```

If you are using some packages to compute large powers of integers, the result is actually not an integer:

```
library(gmp)
bigN <- as.bigz(2)^40
bigN
# Big Integer ('bigz') :
# [1] 1099511627776

str(bigN)
# Class 'bigz'  raw [1:20] 01 00 00 00 ...
```

If the goal however is to save these values into a text file and then read them back, then the following approach can be taken:

```
# Create "big" numbers using gmp package
library(gmp)
bigA <- as.bigz(10)^40
bigB <- as.bigz(9)^40

bigA
# Big Integer ('bigz') :
#  [1] 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000


#Save them as character vector:
# write them to a file
write.csv(data.frame(a=as.character(bigA), b=as.character(bigB)), "myfile.csv", row.names=FALSE)

# Let's take a look at the file
system("cat myfile.csv")
#"a","b"
#"10000000000000000000000000000000000000000","147808829414345923316083210206383297601"

# Read them back as a character strings first.
new.dt <- read.csv("myfile.csv", colClasses=c("character","character"))
str(new.dt)
# 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
#   $ a: chr "10000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
#   $ b: chr "147808829414345923316083210206383297601"

# Convert them back to  "bigz" objects:
bigA.new <- as.bigz(new.dt$a)
bigB.new <- as.bigz(new.dt$b)

bigA
#Big Integer ('bigz') :
#  [1] 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```